# Hide div for one template in AngularJS/Slim

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
.user-header
    .user_signed ng-show="user"
        h3
            | Hello, {{ user.name }}!
            a ui-sref="signOut"  [ Sign out ]
    .user_not_signed ng-hide="user"
        h3
            | Please, 
            a ui-sref="signIn" sign in!
.ui-view.content
    | Loading...
```

It's simple code which shows one or another div according to user model. But now I want to do the following thing - I want to hide "user-header" div if user loads some route (login page). How can I do it? I.e. I want to show user-header for all routes exclude one.

Answer (score 0):

Think several ways to accomplish it.

probably the easiest is checking current url.

html

```
.user-header ng-show="hideHeader()"
    .user_signed ng-show="user"
    ....
```

controller

```
$scope.hideHeader = function(){
    return ['/hidden/url/1', '/hidden/url/2'].indexOf($location.path()) != -1
}
```